# Error al Publicar aplicacion en servidor IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Estoy tratando de publicar un proyecto en el servidor , cuando lo corro en mi computadora si me carga bien el proyecto y si me conecta a la base de datos.
 
**Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -2146232576.**
Alguin mas a tenido este problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**cuando publico el proyecto en el servidor me manda este error:**

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Aplicaciones\MmtoVehicular\bin\roslyn\csc.exe /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+ /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\1f675bfb\006fa443_52f0d201\Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\d8b16822\00a03031_75aece01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\48db3d1c\0074b766_899bd301\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\3a545b06\0069d048_a800d301\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\98a4db61\00cb36c6_96f3d301\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\23568c4d\a6cd6a46_84c5d501\MantenimientoVehicular.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\2.112.3.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\d2ed128a\0074b766_899bd301\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\2b80f179\005f8d6b_cfa8d301\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\7d4d8f25\008b5b5b_7518cf01\WebGrease.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\c4209a06\00405cc9_889bd301\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\20ba9212\005caad7_889bd301\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\6f7dcd8a\0074b766_899bd301\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\8db6f6a0\0074b766_899bd301\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\assembly\dl3\23966d96\007e36de_6f27cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\App_global.asax.e13j-rfb.dll" /debug- /optimize+ /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\App_global.asax.e13j-rfb.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mmtovehicular\1e5230a8\727c25b\App_global.asax.e13j-rfb.1.cs"

Saludos espero y me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Hola, para verificar que todo esté bien, te pregunto te compila en VS y te funcional corriendolo en IIS Expres?

Comment: Válida la siguiente pregunta[reset files bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651282/how-do-you-clear-an-asp-net-app-for-compiling), quizas pueda ayudarte un poco con lo que referencias

Answer (score 0):

Un error de compilación en un sitio publicado, básicamente se refiere a que el pool asociado al website no es el correcto, una mala configuración del pool, o en su caso, la identidad para ejecutar ese pool no tiene los permisos.

Para corregir este comportamiento, asegúrate de lo siguiente:

1. En las propiedades básicas de tu sitio, revisa el pool que tienes asociado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En las propiedades básicas del pool, deberá estar en la versión 4:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. En las propiedades avanzadas del pool, deberá correr bajo la identidad `ApplicationPoolIdentity`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que mi aplicación tenia error de compilación, la ultima opción que tuve fue pasar todo a un proyecto nuevo. fue así cuando me pudo cargar bien y mostrarlo.